# How do you perform a 302 redirect using MVC3 and ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, redirect, http-status-code-302

I'm using Razor, HTML5, MVC3 with C# in an application, where after a user clicks on a link, I open a new window, do some processing, then want to redirect that window with a 302 status code to a link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way to do this in ASP.NET MVC is by having a controller action that returns a redirect `ActionResult`. So inside the controller action you are invoking in this window and doing the processing simply perform a redirect by returning a proper ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // ... some processing
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController");
}
```

When the `Foo` action is invoked (presumably inside the new window) it will do the processing and return a 302 HTTP status code to the client with a new location of `/SomeController/SomeAction`.

If you wanted to redirect to some external url of your application you could do the following:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // ... some processing
    return Redirect("http://someotherdomain.com/somescript");
}
```

As far as creating a link that will open in a new window/tab is concerned you could append the `target="_blank"` attribute on the anchor:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Some link",                 // linkText
    "Foo",                       // action
    "SomeController",            // controller
    null,                        // routeValues
    new { target = "_blank" }    // htmlAttributes
)
```